# DjangoをEC2にデプロイしたがアクセスできない

Tags: django, amazon-ec2

DjangoにHelloWorldと表示させるだけのページを作ってAmazonEC2にアップロードし、インターネット上からアクセスさせたいが、ブラウザで下記表示となりアクセス拒否される。

自分のブラウザから `http://12.34.56.78:8080/`　にアクセス

> このサイトにアクセスできません 12.34.56.78 で接続が拒否されました。 次をお試しください
>
> 接続を確認する プロキシとファイアウォールを確認する ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

- OS: Amazon Linux 2023
- Python: 3.11
- Django: 3.2

### 手順

※ パッケージインストール、マイグレーションなどは実施済み

1. EC2セキュリティグループのインバウンド設定済み
   IPv4    カスタム TCP    TCP 8080    0.0.0.0/0
2. settings.py

   ```py
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
   ```
3. Djangoを起動

   ```bash
   python manage.py runserver 8080
   ```

   `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

### 確認したこと

- 自端末のmac上ローカルホストで起動すると問題なく表示されるため、アプリは動いている
- 同じホスト内から `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/` でアクセスすると表示されるため、アプリは動いている
- nginxを同じポート8080にインストールし起動してみたところ、初期ページが表示されアクセスできるためセキュリティ設定の問題ではなさそう（EC2のパブリックIPV4アドレスに対して`http://12.34.56.78:8080/`でアクセスしています）

Comment: 理由はこちらの記事の内容でしょう。[localhostについて詳しく解説【具体的に解説します】](https://codor.co.jp/django/localhost) そして作業するならこれらの記事の手順に従ってやることになるのでは？ [AWS EC2にDjangoアプリのデプロイ① 〜インスタンス作成からマイグレーション動作確認](https://pala-ghe.com/aws-ec2-django-1-make-instance/), [DjangoをWSGI + EC2 + NGINXでデプロイしてみた](https://qiita.com/RNakao/items/4cf55572d70714c86ff9), [【丁寧解説】秒速でもDjango 3アプリをAWS EC2で公開【Nginx, gunicorn, postgresqlデプロイ】](https://qiita.com/Bashi50/items/d5bc47eeb9668304aaa2), [AWS EC2 で Django で作った Web アプリを動作させる ～動作確認編～](https://coffee-nominagara.com/ec2-on-django-dousakakunin)

Comment: 当然ローカルホストではなくEC2のパブリックIPV4アドレスに対してアクセスしています

Comment: そうだとしたら、何か書籍等を参考にしているならそれを質問に追記し、それまたは後の方で紹介した記事などに書かれた手順を詳細に確認して、結果を追記してみるのが良いと思われます。

Answer (score 4):

サーバーを起動する際に、下記としたら解決した。
デフォルトではループバックアドレスとなり外部からアクセスできない。

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

うまくいく場合とそうでない場合で下記を実行して差異を確認した。

```
$ ss -nlt
```